# how to get the path to file with python when working directory is different

Tags: python, io, working-directory

Consider the following Python file structure

```
Root  
  |---- SubFolder  
  |        |---- generator.py    
  |        |---- config.json        
  |  
  |---- main.py
```

**main.py:**

```
import os 

def main():
    from SubFolder.generator import start

    start(__file__)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    main()
```

**generator.py**

```
import os 
def start(caller: str):

    file_path_s = "./config.json"
    file_path_l = "./SubFolder/config.json"

    exist_s = os.path.exists(file_path_s)
    exist_l = os.path.exists(file_path_l)

    print(f"Caller: {caller}")
    print(f"cwd:{os.getcwd()}")

    print(f"exist {file_path_s}: {exist_s}")
    print(f"exist {file_path_l}: {exist_l}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    start(__file__)
```

**The probplem:**

1. `generator.start()` can be called from `main.py` as well as from `generator.py` itself (executed as main)
2. accordigly the working directory is different
3. when `start()` wants to read the json, the path to to the json is different each case.

   when called from main it should use *./SubFolder/config.json*
   when called from generator it should use *./config.json*

Is there a way to figure out the path to use without the `start()` will do something like the following:

```
def _get_config_path():
    work_dir = os.getcwd()
    sub_folder = "SubFolder"

    index = work_dir.rfind(sub_folder)
    expected = len(work_dir) - len(sub_folder)  
    
    if  index == expected:
        return   "./config.json"
    else:
        return   "./SubFolder/config.json"
```

how this can be achived?

Comment: What is the point of the subfolder?

Comment: if config.json is always located with generatory .py why not just use a relative path from __file__ from within generator.py?

Comment: use `os.path.abspath(__name__)` and from there get parent folder name and based on that take file path

Comment: @SanguineL this is just sample code. The structure and execution are more complex. and sub folder, and root folders contain more files and sub folder. execution method depends on the need

Comment: @AeroEngy not sure i understand. The problem is that i can not just supply a "constant", because it will not work in one of the cases

Comment: @sahasrara62 can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Is it too complicated that you could not use a try-except block? (`except FileNotFoundError:`)

Comment: @SanguineL is it possible. but before try catch can use path.exist. either way - is not an that elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In generator.py just use a relative path to your config

```
from pathlib import Path
def start(caller: str):
    config_path = Path(__file__).parent / "config.json"
    if config_path.exists():
        print(f"config exists:  caller {caller} does not matter")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    start(__file__)
```

Then it doesn't matter who calls it.